# Check if a group contains all items from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, relational-division

I want to check if Sequence is complete at Sequence index.

I have a table `@workREQUIREMENTS` like this that has the required/planned INTRAWORKNO for a sequence:

| INTRAWORKNO |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 20 |
| 30 |

and I have a table `@results` like this:

| SEQUENCE | INTRAWORKNO | part |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 0 |
| 1 | 30 | 0 |
| **2** | **10** | 0 |
| **2** | **20** | 0 |
| **2** | **30** | 0 |
| 3 | 10 | 0 |
| 3 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | 10 | 2 |
| 6 | 40 | 0 |
| 7 | 40 | 0 |
| **8** | **10** | 0 |
| **8** | **20** | 0 |
| **8** | **20** | 1 |
| **8** | **30** | 0 |

How can I delete this SEQUENCEs, where I did not have ALL `INTRAWORKNO` in the corresponding `SEQUENCE`?

As you see,

- sequence 1 has no INTRAWORKNO 20, which eleminates this sequence --> **NG**
- sequence 2 has ALL INTRAWORKNO --> **OK**
- sequence 3 has no INTRAWORKNO 20 and no 30 --> **NG**
- sequence 6 and 7 have no values from the `@workREQUIREMENTS`-table --> **NG**
- sequence 8 has ALL INTRAWORKNO (Intraworkno 20 is divided in sub-parts) --> **OK**

A `group by` clause with a `count` brings not the expected results, because there can be multiple sub-parts (characteristics) of these `SEQUENCE`

The desired results are in bold.

Comment: `count distinct` might work, show your attempt.

Comment: @DaleK: it would not work, because when e.g. on SEQUENCE 8, instead of 30 (last value in demo table), there would be 40 and the count with distinct would also lead to 3, but INTRAWORKNO 30 is not in this sequence.

Comment: When you say "how can I delete", do you really mean delete? Or do you mean "not select"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The looks like relational division. You can use double `not exists` for this ([explanation here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/)):

```
select *
from results as r1
where not exists (
    select *
    from requirements as reqd
    where not exists (
        select *
        from results as r2
        where r1.sequence = r2.sequence and r2.intraworkno = reqd.intraworkno
    )
);
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NLk1v9oA)